# GeoServer 2.19.2 ECW, MrSid, JP2 Stores not present after installing GDAL Extension and GDAL on Linux 20.04

Tags: linux, gdal, geoserver

I've followed the directions at the Geoserver website [here](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/data/raster/gdal.html) for installing the GDAL Image formats on Linux.  However, afterwards there don't seem to be any entries to add ECW, MrSID, or JP2 rasters.

GDAL 3.0.4 is installed:

```
GDAL 3.0.4, released 2020/01/28
```

and the .jar files coped to the lib directory of GeoServer, and it has been restarted.  Other GDAL raster formats now appear in the list of stores to add, but not the three I require the most.  There is no error in the logs indicating an issue, either.

Is there possibly as step I missed?

Answer (score 0):

The [manual](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/data/raster/gdal.html#installing-gdal-native-libraries) clearly states that only GDAL 2.x is supported.

> Starting GeoServer 2.16.x the imageio-ext plugin needs a GDAL version 2.x (tested in particular with 2.2.x and 2.4.x)

Comment: You know, I saw that and figured it was just outdated docs because our Windows installation of GeoServer uses GDAL 3.1.4 and the GDAL Extension works perfectly.

Comment: It might work or it might not - as far as I know the docs are up to date - maybe you should ask on the user list

Comment: It's tested against GDAL 2, what happens to GDAL 3 is unknown.

Comment: FWIW, the GDAL Extension works great on our Windows Geosever 2.19.2  (Platform Independent Binary installation) with GDAL 3.1.4.  On the Ubuntu JAR installation, the functionality exposed by the GDAL extension works fine, but it doesn't expose the ability to create stores from ECW, SID, or JP2 sources.  The frustrating things is that there doesn't seem to be a way to use an earlier version of GDAL on Ubuntu 20.04.  At least not a way I can figure out.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure that ECW & SID etc are ever built in to GDAL on unix

Comment: Well, golly....that might be the answer.  A simple gdalinfo --formats show that ECW and SID files are not supported.  However, strangely JP2 is.  I wonder what THAT one isn't presented as an available store option.

Comment: Only the JP2OpenJPEG driver which I've never managed to make work

Comment: Just to confirm:

gdalinfo --formats | grep -i 'Jp.\|sid\|ECW' shows:
JPEG -raster- (rwv): JPEG JFIF
  JP2OpenJPEG -raster,vector- (rwv): JPEG-2000 driver based on OpenJPEG library
  JPEGLS -raster- (rwv): JPEGLS

Comment: OK, thanks guys, I think we have our answer to why it doesn't work.